# Facebook App versus Facebook Owner Profile

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm planning to build an app that gets my friends (I am the app owner). I don't need people to login or anything. The app is just for me. Question: do I need to ask for permissions or an app id and app secret should suffice? Facebook documentation for developers does not seem to cover this specific case...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need permission `user_friends` to access a user’s friends; but – you can get only those friends that are users of your app as well, and have granted that same permission on their part. (And the documentation does cover this in quite clear terms, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/friends#read)

Comment: I meant my friends as me in the role of app owner! Do you understand that?

Comment: Yes. Now all you have to understand, is that that makes no difference whatsoever :-)

Comment: This answers my question then. Thanks!